# How right to use the DRY principle in NestJS when creating controllers?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Good day !

I created a basic controller **BaseController** with basic endpoints...

```
import { Get, Post, Put, Delete, HttpStatus, Request, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessageCodeError } from './../index';

export class BaseController {
    public dataService: any;

    constructor(public DataService: any) {
        this.dataService = DataService;
    }

    @Get('/')
    public async findAndCountAll(@Request() req, @Response() res) {
        const params = req.query;
        const offset = Number(params.skip) || 0;
        const limit = Number(params.limit) || 10;
        delete params.offset;
        delete params.limit;

        const records = await this.dataService.findAndCountAll({ where: params, offset, limit });
        return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({ total: records.count, data: records.rows });
    }
}
```

I try to use it in other controllers. For example, in **UserController**...

```
import { Controller, Get, Post, Put, Delete, HttpStatus, Request, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessageCodeError } from '../common/index';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

import { BaseController } from './../common/shared/base.controller';

@Controller('users')
export class UserController extends BaseController {

    constructor(public userService: UserService) {
        super(userService);
    }

}
```

I thought since I was in class **UserController** doing inheritance from class **BaseController**, then the functions (which act as endpoints) should be available in **UserController**. But it seems that I was wrong...

[image: screenshot of *GET* request to *host:port/users*]

The database is OK, the connection is stable, the code is working (at least was before I decided to take out endpoints from the **UserController** to the **BaseController**). What could be the mistake ?

Comment: Please post code not pictures, we can copy paste code, not pictures

Comment: I can suggest do as many controllers, as needed. Only then try to extract base.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your `BaseController` with `@Controller()` decorator.

```
import { Get, Post, Put, Delete, HttpStatus, Request, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessageCodeError } from './../index';

@Controller()
export class BaseController {
     public dataService: any;

     constructor(public DataService: any) {
         this.dataService = DataService;
     }

     @Get('/')
     public async findAndCountAll(@Request() req, @Response() res) {
         const params = req.query;
         const offset = Number(params.skip) || 0;
         const limit = Number(params.limit) || 10;
         delete params.offset;
         delete params.limit;

         const records = await this.dataService.findAndCountAll({ where: params, offset, limit });
         return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).send({ total: records.count, data: records.rows });
     }
}
```